# Listview's first item is always selected

Tags: android, listview, selector

I'm using a custom view to display items in a listview. For some reason every time the list is populated; the first item is shown as selected (ie; orange highlight). I've tried everything I can think about to solve it; any ideas?

Comment: can you post some code where you populate your list?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to request focus from the parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

This would happen when you launch your Activity using the keyboard (you are thus in key mode, which causes the first focusable item to be focused.) How is that a bad thing?